# Need Users to Re-authenticate with NTLM

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication, ntlm

I'm NTLM (authenication="windows" in the web.config) with an asp.net mvc 2.0 site.

Right now once a user logs in it keeps them logged in for weeks at a time.

The use of the application is being opened up to users who share computers that use logged in service accounts.

I need the site to reprompt each user for their AD credentials each time in order to handle these users.   (Activity on the site must be linked to a uniquely identified user.)

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Trey Carroll

Comment: Is each user signing on to a different account in the domain?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like even though users have a domain logon, that they are accessing the terminals via a common "kiosk account".   This means that I need to challenge each visitor the first time they access the page, but then allow them to navigate the situe under those credentials for the duration of their session.   The suggestiong to switch over to Forms auth is sounding like a good recommendation at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to do this is to handle the [Http Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789031.aspx) process using the `HTTP 401 challenge`.

The principle is to refuse the credentials, even if they are valid to force all users (or somes depending on AD attributes/code parameters...) to retype their credentials.

You have to send `HTTP 401` codes in the response to indicate to the browser that the credentials which have been sent are not accepted. 
Depending on the browser configuration, you have to send 1 to 3 `401` responses (you can use cookies to handle the counter) to force the browser to prompt the user, so count up to 3.

```
if (mycounter < 3)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 401; 
    Response.End();
}
```

[NTLM Authentication Scheme for HTTP](http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html)

[IIS Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: A similar (but not duplicated) question was asked and I answered in a more detailed manner : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244860/iis-site-for-both-intranet-and-anonymous-users/20290262#20290262

Answer (score 2):

I would change the app to use Forms authentication instead.  You can still validate the credentials against AD, but you'll be able to enforce the login requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that they just use a browser that doesn't support NTLM automatically?  For example when I go to our Sharepoint server I have to login with my domain credentials in Firefox.