# IIS site for both intranet and anonymous users

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I'm working on an application that should be available to intranet users running under their own account (Windows authentication). This is easily configured and works.

Now if users are not logged in to the domain (because they are off site or on a device that is not logged in) they should still be able to use the application, minus some personalized functionality.

So to sum that up, this is what I would like to happen:

1. User opens the application. If windows credentials are available the browser sents them to IIS.
2. If the users credentials are recieved, the application runs under these credentials (I've got that covered).
3. If the users credentials are not recieved, the application runs under the IIS anonymous account and personalized functionality is turned off (I've got that covered as well).

What I can't get to work is to optionally send the credentials. If I turn on windows authentication, I'll be logged in, which is fine. However if I try to access the site without sending credentials I'll get a 401, which makes sense. So I turn on anonymous authentication and now credentials are never sent.

This actually makes sense, because IIS never requests for authentication from the browser. The question is, how do I make this scenario work?

Comment: There's an article on MSDN about mixing Windows and Forms authentication.  It contains info that might help in your scenario: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx

Comment: I've looked into this article. It may prove an inspiration for a solution, although I think using a custom 401 error is a bit of a hack. I'll have to consult with others in the team first.

Comment: When you write "So I turn on anonymous authentication and now credentials are never sent." You mean the credentials are never sent even if you enable Anonymous Authentication AND Windows Authentication ? If so, it looks like a browser (IE?) configuration behavior.

Comment: @JoeBilly That is what I mean. I've configured the site I'm testing with as a trusted site and enabled sending the current windows credentials by default. What I understand of the HTTP authentication mechanism is that it will only do this based on a server request for authentication.

Answer (score 3):

You are right on your analysis. 
[HTTP authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789031.aspx) schemes are :

- Anonymous access
- Challenge-Response authentications

  - Negotiate (Kerberos)
  - NTLM
  - Digest
- Basic authentication

On IIS (and most HTTP servers), the default authentication process respect the order above. ie. If anonymous access succeeded (will not get into details here) others authentication providers are ignored even if they are enabled.

**HTTP 401 Challenge**

**If you want to manage multiple authentication methods and providers you have to use a mechanism which refuse the credentials when you consider them invalid. You can achieve this by sending `401` Responses. This is called `HTTP 401 Challenge`.**

The idea is to tell to the client (browser) that the credentials used for the requested resource are refused.

Depending on the scenario and the client configuration, the client may handle an authentication. And in this case the authentication process may vary : Challenge-Response providers needs a certain number of exchanges to valid the credentials.

Anyway, in your case, with anonymous access enabled, the first `401` response will be interpreted by the browser as "This request requires an authentication". The server automatically include the supported authentication providers in the response header if they are enabled on the server side.

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
> WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
> WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
> WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth",algorithm=MD5-sess,nonce="+Upgraded+v1b3a89710edce01754fd608...",charset=utf-8,realm="Digest"
> WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="host"
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> Content-Length: 0
> Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
> ```

If your browser is correctly configured to send the credentials for the zone of your web application (you said so), it'll automatically use the first authentication provider it knows (`NTLM` for example) and re-process the request with the credentials it knows (Windows credentials in your case).

> ```
> GET http://host/yourpage.aspx HTTP/1.1
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFASgKAAAADw==
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> ```

When the authentication process fail, the server automatically send a `403 Forbidden` response to the client to avoid too much traffic. A `403` response stops the challenge. The good news is it takes some challenge to happen : more than 4.
And usually, an HTTP authentication challenge needs near to 3 Challenge-Response maximum to succeed (3 for `NTLM` and 2 for `Negotiate -Kerberos-`).

Since you allow anonymous access, the server will not block the client requests and your pages will be called with anonymous credentials. You can still interact with your client in your page by setting yourself the `HTTP Response Code`. As already said, its only works if you enable another authentication provider in addition to `Anonymous`.

So the trick is to handle it with a counter on your server side and say "if my auth session/cookie counter is more than 3, my client can't authenticate with the server. Let's say he is anonymous".

**Some Code**

I didn't do exactly what you need but you can adapt my code :

```
    int i = 3;
    int j = 0;
    HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

    // Record authentication process
    HttpCookie httpCookie2 = httpContext.Request.Cookies["loginAttemptCount"];
    if (httpCookie2 == null || httpCookie2.Value == String.Empty)
    {
        httpCookie2 = new HttpCookie("loginAttemptCount");
    }
    else
    {
        j = Int32.Parse(httpCookie2.Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    j = (j + 1) % i;

    string user = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];

    // Send 401 responses to authenticate the user
    if (j != 0 && user == String.Empty)
    {
        httpCookie2.Value = j.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie2);
        Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return;
    }

    httpCookie2.Value = String.Empty;
    httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie2);
```

If needed, you can check the authorization provider in the `Authorization` header.

```
Request.Headers["Authorization"]
```

You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to trace your HTTP headers.

Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Just so I'm clear before implementing anything. The basic idea is to allow anonymous in IIS and handle authentication at a later stage. Then return a 401 the first 3 times and allow access the 4th time?

Comment: Yep you got it, note that you need at least two authentications methods enabled on your server side : `Anonymous Authentication` **and** one more like `Windows Authentication` to use the `HTTP 401 Challenge`. Pointed out in my answer.